# Ask a list of integer in python in one line

Tags: python, list

```
def entree_liste():
    liste_entier = []
    liste_nombre = int(input("Enter list of number separate by space :"))
    for chiffre in range(liste_nombre):
        liste_entier.append(chiffre)
    print(liste_entier)
```

and my error

```
liste_nombre = int(input("Enter list of number separate by space :"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '22 33 44 55'
```

Basically, I am asking the user for a list of int. If I do `liste_entier = list(liste_nombre)` they count space as an integer and I don't want to have space in my list only the integer.

Comment: split `liste_nombre` first (dont convert to `int`) ... and `map` it to `int` later

Answer (score 3):

The function `int()` will convert a *single value* to integer.  But you have one giant string with many integer values embedded in it.  To solve this problem, first split the giant string into a collection (in this case, a list) of smaller strings, each containing only one integer and then convert each of those strings separately.

To perform the splitting operation, you can use the Python string method .split().  That will return a list of strings.  Each of those strings can then be converted to integer:

```
 # get list as string
 list_nombre = input("Enter list of numbers separated by space:")
 # create list of smaller strings, each with one integer-as-string
 list_of_int_strings = list_nombre.split(' ') 
 # convert list of strings to list of integers
 list_of_ints = []
 for int_string in list_of_int_strings:
      list_of_ints.append(int(int_string)
```

However, in Python we would more concisely write:

```
 list_nombre = input("Enter list of numbers separated by space:")

 list_of_ints = ([int(s) for s in list_nombre.split(' ')])
```

Comment: why not `map(int, ...)` and one can just `.split()` with no arguments

Comment: @Suor, `map` doesn't return a list in Python3. Better to just get in the habit of using list comprehension

Comment: @gnibber that's just a wrong argument to use list comprehensions.

Comment: Yes, you *can* use split without arguments but I think it's considerably clearer for this beginning programmer to be more explicit.  As for the list comprehension, that's my preference and, I believe, more idiomatically common in Python -- if you prefer map(), feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
liste_entier = list(map(int, input("Enter list of number separate by space :").split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is read in the string, of ints separated by spaces then explode it, and case the entires to int.

```
input = raw_input("Enter list of number separate by space :")

input.split()
```

then cast he elements to int

its always safer to read in strings, then deal with the return.

Comment: Actually better to use just `.split()`. Otherwise if the user accidentally enters two spaces in a row you would get an error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit that, but I assume he knows what he is dong, just pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As @Larry suggests, this is a reasonable way to write this in Python

```
list_nombre = input("Enter list of numbers separated by space:")
list_of_ints = [int(s) for s in list_nombre.split()]
```

The problem is that it's not possible to handle exceptions inside the list comprehension. To do this, you may want to write your own, more robust/helpful conversion function

```
def convert_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError as e:
        print e
        return None

list_nombre = input("Enter list of numbers separated by space:")
list_of_ints = [convert_int(s) for s in list_nombre.split()]
```

Comment: Will that not give you some mysterious `None`s in the result of you comprehension?  I would imagine that a thrown Exception would be the expected result of an input string with non-integer input.

Comment: @LarryLustig, it's an _example_ of how to include an exception handler. Hardly "mysterious" since the exception is being printed out

Answer (score 0):

The `int()` function will only take a string that contains only digits. Since a space is not a digit, it will cause an error. To fix this problem, first split the string into a list of smaller strings, and then convert each of the smaller strings into an integer if possible.

```
 string = input('Enter list of space separated numbers: ')
 numbers = [int(n) for n in string.split() if n.isdigit()]
```